# Printchart title in highcharts when clicking print button when chart title is null

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, printing, highcharts

hi i am working on highhchart and stuck on a point which sounds very simple but cant find any answer on it .

i am setting the chart title null when defining highcharts

but on export am adding the chart title like

```
 exporting: {
             filename: '<?php echo $description ; ?>',
             buttons: {
                 exportButton: {
                     menuItems: [{
                         text: 'Export Chart',
                         onclick: function () {
                             this.exportChart({}, {
                                title: {
                                    text: '<?php echo $description  ; ?>',
                                      style: {
                                            width: '450px'
                                        }
                                }
                            });
                         }
                     }, 
                     null,
                     null,
                     null]
                 }
             }
         }
```

am not able to configure how to add chart title and and other parameters when prining the chart as i do on export .

this is my working fiddle to export a chart 
http://jsfiddle.net/4SwvV/

which export with a title on export when chart is set to null

i am not getting how to achive this in print . does print allow to set option like this to export chart title/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of catch menuitemclick, you can set this option in exporting

chartOphttp://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#exporting.chartOptions

So as a result it looks like http://jsfiddle.net/4SwvV/:

```
exporting: {
        filename: 'Export chart',
        chartOptions:{
            title:{
                text:'Exported chart'
            }
        },
        buttons: {
            exportButton: {
                menuItems: [{
                    text: 'Export Chart'
                },
                null,
                null,
                null]
            }
        }
    },
```

EDIT:

You can use not perfect solution http://jsfiddle.net/4SwvV/4/ :

```
 title: {
        useHTML: true,
        text: '<div id="title">Example title</div>',
        style: {
            width: '300px'
        }
    },
```

Buttons:

```
 onclick: function () {
                        $('#title').hide();
                        chart.print();
                        $('#title').show();
                    }
```

Comment: i tried your example here http://jsfiddle.net/4SwvV/3/  it sounds good the option defined in chart option reflect in exporting but not whn i try to print the chart title seems missing when i want to print it .

Comment: as it states"Additional chart options to be merged into an exported chart. For example, the exported chart can be given a specific width and height, or a printer-friendly color scheme. Defaults to null." is there any chart option that can be configured for printing

Comment: this does seem to work and answer my question http://jsfiddle.net/4SwvV/8/   but cant with all page being exported with chart . i wanted export and chart to work as same though :)